# Ez publish 4.7: embed twit in xml block

Tags: ezpublish

I want to embed a tweet into xml block using ezoe. Is there any way to embed custom html code into it?
Tweet embed code looks like this:

```
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>Bla bla </p>&mdash; Air France    (@airfrance) <a href="https://twitter.com/airfrance/status/454220292685320192">April 9,   2014</a></blockquote><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the `html` class for the `literal` tag.

**settings/content.ini**

```
[literal]
AvailableClasses[]
# The class 'html' is disabled by default because it gives editors the
# possibility to insert html and javascript code in XML blocks.
# Don't enable the 'html' class unless you really trust all users who has
# privileges to edit objects containing XML blocks.
#AvailableClasses[]=html
CustomAttributes[]
```

=> reproduce the following in your admin & front siteaccesses

**settings/siteaccess/youradminsiteaccess/content.ini.append.php**
and **settings/siteaccess/yourfrontsiteaccess/content.ini.append.php**

```
[literal]
AvailableClasses[]=html
```

Once done, you'll be able to choose the `html` class.

That said, enabling this feature suggests that contributors are aware of and concerned by possible security issues such as XSS. This should never be enabled for anonymous users (when you let them create comment objects with rich text fields for instance).

Comment: Thanks :). I will do it in that way